# Transform symlink module with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have symlink module in my project which contains JS features that should be transpiled with Babel:

```
  "dependencies": {
     "my-lib": "file:../../path/to/lib"
  }
```

So when I am tying to test my project it looks like `my-lib` is not transpiled because Jest can not preserve symlink path(so my `transformIgnorePatterns` does not work) and tests failed with syntax error in `import`  statement in `my-lib` index file.

Is there any workaround to make it work?

Here is my jest config if needed:

```
module.exports = {
    rootDir: './',
    roots: ['<rootDir>', '<rootDir>/tests/'],
    setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/tests/setupComponents.js'],
    moduleDirectories: ["node_modules"],
    moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'vue'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/source/$1'
    },
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.vue$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest',
        '^.+\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest'
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        'node_modules\/(?!(my-lib)/)'
    ],
    snapshotSerializers: [
        '<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-serializer-vue'
    ],
    collectCoverage: true,
    collectCoverageFrom: [
       "<rootDir>/source/**/*.{js,vue}"
    ],
    coverageReporters: ["text", "text-summary"]
}
```

Comment: Once this PR is merged, I think issue will be addressed. I'm eagerly waiting for it too. https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/7364

Comment: @GeorgeK Thanks! Yeah, I saw some issues in jest's github too. Unfortunately, can not wait for this, so for now, as workaround, I wrote script which copies all symlink libraries to `node_modules` to temporary folder before tests run and added `moduleNameMapper`s to say jest that libs can be found in temp dir.

Comment: The PR was unfortunately closed.   @MaxSinev do you still have the script you created to make that workaround?

Comment: @JGuerra yes I have but don't know if it still works or not https://gist.github.com/maxsinev/7dad75c05c2532b4131f9caab99e5c38 if you don't mind I also would suggest to look at npm/pnpm workspace feature, it looks like it can solve this issue

Comment: Thanks! @MaxSinev. Partially solved the issue by creating a hardlink instead of a softlink. I just removed the flag `-s` en executing the commando `ln`. Will anyways check your script.